# CSS Align top of child container to bottom of parent container

Tags: html, css

Consider this HTML

```
<div class="parent">
    <a href="#">Parent</a>
    <div class="child">
        <a href="#">Child</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is position the top of `child` to the bottom of `parent`.

Here's my CSS so far:

```
.parent {
    position: relative;
}

.child {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

What this achieves is this:

[image: Example 1]

What I want to achieve is this:

[image: Example 2]

**Please note:** I do not know the height of either the parent or child container, and don't really want to set an arbitrary height, and I don't want to revert to using JavaScript.

Comment: can't you just toss `<br>` there, and set this br padding and margin if necessary?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
.parent {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #F00;
}

.child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #00F;
}
```

Comment: I feel really stupid now, `top: 100%` is what I was looking for

Answer (score 6):

You can do this with [`transform: translateY(100%)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translateY)

The **translateY()** CSS function moves the element vertically on the plane. This transformation is characterized by a `<length>` defining how much it moves vertically.
    `translateY(ty)` is a **shortcut** for `translate(0, ty)`.

[image]

```css
.parent {
    position: relative;
    background: red;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50vh;
}

.child {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: blue;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    transform: translateY(100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <a href="#">Parent</a>
    <div class="child">
        <a href="#">Child</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unlike the other solutions out there, this solution also works for positioning the _child element directly above the parent element._  Just use a negative **Y:** `transform: translateY(-100%);`  It works because the value is for the child **not** the parent.